# Print to a local Multi-Function Printer while connected to Office network with Remote Desktop

Tags: desktop, remote, network-printer

User trying to print locally to a Multi-Function Printer while connected to Office network with Remote Desktop (Windows 7) Local printer (MF device attached to LPT1) does not show up in list of available printers. Disconnect from Remote Desktop and it becomes available. Set up local printer as device on local network and still no joy. Suggested solution? Options?
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to make sure you have selected printers under options in the RDP clinet  Local Devices and Resources.

You may also require the driver exist on the RDP server.